# How do I help to heal a bird that has fallen from its nest?

Tags: birds, strays

I was going to mow my lawn, when I heard a eally high pitched squeal from my tree. I went over to examine, and their was a small blue bird. I don't really see blur birds, and they aren't exactly what you can consider your common bird. I want to do anything I can to help the birdy heal. It doesn't seem exactly hurt, and I need to know what to do because it will not climd back into its tree, and is so scared. I feel so bad for the poor guy!

Comment: If it has sustained any injury or not, you must visit vet.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic [per this meta post](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/are-questions-about-semi-domesticated-wild-animals-on-topic) it would be ok on The Great Outdoors, but would be duplicate there so not migrating [How should I rescue a baby bird, including when it's wet?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19625)

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are able to put the bird back into its nest, there is very little you can do.

It is sad, but true; sometimes the strongest chick in a nest pushes its siblings out of the nest. This is nature's way to be sure the strongest chick survives.

If the chick is almost ready to fly you can try to feed it back to health, but this is very hard to do. First of all, you need to give it the right food and you need to feed it about every 20 minutes; and second, you need to keep it warm and this is hard, hard to do; it needs a temperature of about 39 °C (this is the body temperature of many birds).

You can ask a vet if there are any organisations doing bird rescue in your area.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it in a warm place and feed it , the first thing it needs is water.  If you can put back into the nest that would be good.In the states it would likely be a bluebird but they are not nesting in winter. You should be able to identify it and find out what food it needs on the internet, feed it soon. Vets are not likely much help ; for our parrots we must search to find a vet that knows much about them. I raised a crow , its nest was 80 ft high so no help. It was very young. I was able to feed it but mostly by luck ( before the "net"). It left the following spring although it was loose outside the first summer and fall, it hung around the house.